# Unable to show hide Elements Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

MY JQuery code is running fine, but where I place it, it won't work. I tried a lot of things but unable to execute it.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html5 lang="en">

<head>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("select").change(function () {
               $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
                   var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
                   if (optionValue) {
                       $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                       $("." + optionValue).show();
                   } else {
                       $(".box").hide();
                   }
               });
           }).change();
       });
</script>


</head>
<body>
    </section>

    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="block-header">
            </div>

            <!-- #END# Basic Example | Vertical Layout -->
            <!-- Advanced Form Example With Validation -->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                           <div class="body">




                            <form id="wizard_with_validation" method="POST" class="box">

                                  <h3>CRITERIA</h3>

                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="body">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p>
                                        <b>Business Type</b> <span style="color:red">*</span>
                                    </p>
                                        <div class="form-group form-float">
                                        <select class="form-control">
                                        <option selected disabled>Choose Business Type</option>
                                        <option  id="sp" value="box">Sole proprietorship</option>
                                        <option id="rp" value="Registered">Registered</option>
                                        <option id="llc" value="Limited">Limited Company</option>
                                        <option id="plc" value="Private">Private limited Company</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                    <div class="box">    
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p><b>NTN Certificate</b> <span style="color:red">*</span></p>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                     <div class="form-line">
                                     <input type="file" class="form-control" name="ntncert" id="ntncert">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p><b>NTN Registration Date</b> <span style="color:red">*</span></p>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="ntncert" id="ntncert">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                </div>
                                 </div>
                                </fieldset>
```

If I place this code After `<div class="body">` tag, it works fine, but if I place it where it is currently, it is not working. I do not know what went wrong in this place.

Comment: remove the section tag that closed next to the open tag of body.. I think that maybe the issue. and make sure to add scripts inside of the body.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clear with what you mean by "it works if I place this code after tag"? Also, what do you mean by unable to execute it? Do you have errors in your console that you could share? Have you done troubleshooting with debugger to see if you're getting into the callbacks that you've defined?

Comment: @Jishnuvp it does not work even after removing the <section> tag from it.

Comment: @CrankyCoder if i place this code right after the <div class='body'> it execute accurate, if i place it in the <field> tag, JQuery runs and hide the desired elements, but upon selection it does not show elements which are hidden. i have dont troubleshooting too but there is no use.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to place your script just before the `</body>` tag. You want to wait for the HTML DOM to be built before making attempts to modify it with the JavaScript. Analogy : you pay for the groceries after you've brought the items to the cashier, not before.

Edit:  Two other problems caught my attention : 
- You have typos (random `</section>` tag without a starting one, no closing tags for the fieldset and subsequent divs, "html5" tag.
- You call the `change()` function just after defining the event, which means once an event is triggered it will trigger itself indefinitely.

Comment: Which, of course, is why you wrap it in `$(document).ready(function () {` - as OP has done

Comment: `$(id).change(function() {}).change()` is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) and will define the event then trigger it once; it's a standard construct for setup+initialise. It's not the same as `$(id).change(function() { $(this).change() })` which will, as you rightly say, cause an infinite loop.

Comment: (not trying to pick on your answer, just pointing things out) :)

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax be `$(id).change(function(){...})();` in this case ?

Comment: Good point, that is the syntax for an IIFE.  You are correct, this is not an IIFE in that sense, apologies for the confusion.  Not sure if there's a specific term then, but it lets you setup the event then fire that event immediately due to the nice way jquery chains.  The alternative would be like:  `$(id).change(myHandler);function myHandler() { handle }); myHandler();` but with `.change()` also calling any other event handlers that may exist.